# write pandas dataframe to excel and save at desired directory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I have a pandas dataframe and is able to write the dataframe in excel and save it at a predefined path which is root directory. But i want to use windows save as feature, so as I can define any path and anyfile name to the excel file. second code is giving following error
"**TypeError: write() argument must be str, not DataFrame**"

code that is working with predefined path and file name :

```
df = pandas.read_sql(sql_str, con=globals()['con'])
df.to_excel('RULE_DUMP.xlsx', sheet_name='CR_DUMP')
```

code that is not working

```
df = pandas.read_sql(sql_str, con=globals()['con'])
file = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('excel file', '*.xlsx')], defaultextension='.xlsx')
fob = open(file, 'w')
fob.write(df)
fob.close()
```

Comment: get  location string from tkinter as path for excel file and pass it to pandas [to_excel method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: May this code work for you`file = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir="/", title="select A files", filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")))`

Comment: @NikolayTsvetanov can you share the sample code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
file_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('excel file', '*.xlsx')], defaultextension='.xlsx')

df.to_excel(file_name, sheet_name='CR_DUMP')
```

`filedialog.asksaveasfilename` - returns file name as string